# How to search for a specific value in an array of objects based on another value [JavaScript]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I search for a specific value in an array of objects based on another value? For example, I have the ID of a post and want to check if I have the required permissions for that particular Post ID.

```
Posts = [
    {
      Id: '123',
      Permission: 'True',
      Name: 'XY'
      //Other key value pairs
     },
    {
      Id: '456',     
      Permission: 'False'
      Name: 'AB'
      //Other key value pairs
    } 
];
```

My current approach goes in this direction.

```
if (posts.some(e => e.Permission === true && e.Id == PostId)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false ;
      }
```

I appreciate any support.

Comment: sounds like [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To find the element

```js
const arr = arr.find(p => p.property == someValue);
```

This will return undefined if the element is not found and return the element if found.

#### To find the index of the element

If you only want the index use `findIdex`

```js
const index = arr.findIndex(p => p.property == someValue);
```

If the element is not found it will return `-1` and if found return the index.

#### To check if the element is present i.e bool value

Your current implementation does that. You can simply return that.

```js
return posts.some(e => e.Permission === true && e.Id == PostId)
```

Seems like you are confusing with how to use the value from somewhere else to search in the array, you can always pass in a callback and check that.

```js
value => value.somProp == value1 && value.otherProp == value2 || someOtherChek(value)
```

Comment: Thanks @Subesh. You are right, I confused that 'e.Id' is case sensitive. After correcting it, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter

```
Posts = [
{
  Id: '123',
  Permission: 'True',
  Name: 'XY'
  //Other values
 },
{
  Id: '456',     
  Permission: 'False'
  Name: 'AB'
  //Other values
}
```

];

```
let id='123';
let filtered=Posts.filter(i=> i. Permission===true && i.Id===id);
```